# Use openAPIV3Schema for validatiing PersistentVolumeClaim

Tags: kubernetes

I want to use openAPIV3Scheme to validate a PersistentVolumeClaim like this:

```
     - metadata:
          name: data
      spec:
          accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
          resources:
              requests:
                  storage: 1Gi
```

I am not sure how should I define types, properties, etc in the yaml file. Would you please give me some pointers?

Comment: Could you explain a little further? What should be validated? and how exactly you need it validated? It's just not clear to me if you want to override some fields or just ensure they are present?

Comment: In the helm chart I would like to add a scheme to validate the fields (to make sure they are present and types are correct) of a PVC like the above one. I tried different things but I couldn't get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To validate OpenAPI schema of Kubernetes manifest files generated by helm, you need to use a dedicated (external) tools, for instance: [kubeval](https://kubeval.instrumenta.dev/) or jsonschema client with predefined [kubernetes-json](https://github.com/instrumenta/kubernetes-json-schema) schema.

Here is an example usage of `kubeval` against invalid PVC resource:

```
helm template jenkins-issue . | kubeval -v 1.15.3 --strict

PASS - jenkins/templates/service-account.yaml contains a valid ServiceAccount (default.jenkins-issue)
PASS - jenkins/templates/secret.yaml contains a valid Secret (default.jenkins-issue)
PASS - jenkins/templates/config.yaml contains a valid ConfigMap (default.jenkins-issue)
PASS - jenkins/templates/tests/test-config.yaml contains a valid ConfigMap (default.jenkins-issue-tests)
WARN - jenkins/templates/home-pvc.yaml contains an invalid PersistentVolumeClaim (default.jenkins-issue) - accessModess: Additional property accessModess is not allowed
PASS - jenkins/templates/rbac.yaml contains a valid Role (default.jenkins-issue-schedule-agents)
PASS - jenkins/templates/rbac.yaml contains a valid RoleBinding (default.jenkins-issue-schedule-agents)
PASS - jenkins/templates/jenkins-agent-svc.yaml contains a valid Service (default.jenkins-issue-agent)
PASS - jenkins/templates/jenkins-master-svc.yaml contains a valid Service (default.jenkins-issue)
PASS - jenkins/templates/jenkins-master-deployment.yaml contains a valid Deployment (default.jenkins-issue)
PASS - jenkins/templates/tests/jenkins-test.yaml contains a valid Pod (default.jenkins-issue-ui-test-kr3kq)
```

If you just want to validate fields in helm's `values.yaml` file (check whether are present or are of valid type), you can use JSON schemas validation introduced with helm v3 (`helm lint`), as explained in [this](https://www.arthurkoziel.com/validate-helm-chart-values-with-json-schemas/) bog post.

Yet another option to validate OpenAPI schema of Kubernetes API resources, is to pipe the output of `helm` to `kubectl` with API server's `dry-run` mode enabled, e.g.

```
cat pvc.yaml | kubectl apply -f - --validate --server-dry-run

The PersistentVolumeClaim "my-jenkins-new" is invalid: spec.accessModes: Unsupported value: "ReadWriteOnces": supported values: "ReadOnlyMany", "ReadWriteMany", "ReadWriteOnce"
```

I hope this answers your question.